# Error: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, operands

I'm traying to write a code that have r_1 and r_2 are vectors and the other parameters are float. I got this error and i don't know why ! i think the problem in type of n_1 or n_H

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
#import math
r_1=[]
for i in range(3):
    v=input("Elemnts1:  ")
    r_1 = append(r_1,v)
print(r_1)
r_2=[]
for i in range(3):
    v=input("Elemnts2:  ")
    r_2 = append(r_2,v)
print(r_2)
Delta_theta=float(input("Delta_theta="))
t_1=float(input("t_1="))
t_2=float(input("t_2=")) 
Delta_t= t_2 - t_1

def orbit_determination(r_1,r_2,Delta_theta,Delta_t):
    mu=398600.0
    m=(mu*(Delta_t)**2)/(2*np.sqrt(np.dot(r_1,r_2))*np.cos(Delta_theta/2))**3
    L_1= (r_1+r_2)/4*np.sqrt(np.dot(r_1,r_2))*np.cos(Delta_theta/2)
    L= L_1 -(1/2)
    n_H=(12/22)+(10/22)*np.sqrt(1+((44*m)/9*(L+(5/6))))
    n_1=n_H+0.1
#compute the Semi-parameter from
    p=(n_1**2)*np.cross((r_1,r_2)**2)/mu*((Delta_t)**2)


 File "orbit_determinition11.py", line 51, in <module>
    orbit_determination(r_1,r_2,Delta_theta,Delta_t)
  File "orbit_determinition11.py", line 27, in orbit_determination
    p=(n_1**2)*np.cross((r_1,r_2)**2)/mu*((Delta_t)**2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Comment: So what do you expect `(r_1,r_2)**2` to do?

Answer (score 1):

As [Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209921/matthias) hints to in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67266350/error-unsupported-operand-types-for-or-pow-tuple-and-int/67266617#comment118898196_67266350)

> So what do you expect `(r_1,r_2)**2` to do?

The problem is on the line

```py
p=(n_1**2)*np.cross((r_1,r_2)**2)/mu*((Delta_t)**2)
```

specifically

```py
np.cross((r_1,r_2)**2)
```

As you're calling [`np.cross`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html) which

> Return the cross product of two (arrays of) vectors.
>
> Returns
> `c: ndarray`
>
> Vector cross product(s).

The argument you're passing it is `(r_1,r_2)**2` which constructs [a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple) of the `r_1` and `r_2` vectors and attempts to raise it to the power of two (which isn't supported), which is why you're getting

> ```
>  File "orbit_determinition11.py", line 27, in orbit_determination
>    p=(n_1**2)*np.cross((r_1,r_2)**2)/mu*((Delta_t)**2)
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'
> ```

---

It looks like `n_1`, `mu`, and `Delta_t` are floats - though it's not clear from your code what you're trying to do and what `p` is supposed to be:

If `p` is a vector, possibly the `**2` is a typo:

```py
p=(n_1**2)*np.cross(r_1,r_2)/mu*((Delta_t)**2)
```

If `p` is a float, possibly `np.dot` was meant:

```py
p=(n_1**2)*((np.dot(r_1,r_2))**2)/mu*((Delta_t)**2)
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not that familiar with Python and its syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring float numbers, you need to use `.` , so when you introduce a number in the variables you need to make sure that the format is `2.3` and not `2,3`, otherwise you are declaring a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should add
`p = int(p)`
before line 27.
I guess it might work.